# symlink to move steam games to cold storage?

Tags: steam, linux

I am building a linux desktop and have 250 GB SSD and 2 TB HDD. I want to install my steam games (which I play actively) on the SSD, but if/when I don't play them, I'd like to move them on to the larger HDD.

If I just symlink the directories to the 2 TB HDD cold storage location, will Steam still be able to access them if I want to load them up?

Answer (score 2):

I'd expect so, but the best way to check would be to try it.

```
cp ./.steam/game_data/ ./2tb/blah
mv ./.steam/game_data/ ./.steam/old_game_data
ln -s ./2tb/blah/ ./.steam/game_data
```

And fire up steam, see what it thinks.

If it fails, remove the symlink and move the game_data back.